# In Haskell, how do you use 'head' without creating a separate function?

Tags: haskell, head

I'm very new to using Haskell and I'm unsure about how 'head' works. From my understanding it returns the first element in a list. I've been trying to use it, but I keep getting errors. I added a workaround by creating a separate function that finds the head, however that seems like it should be unnecessary.

I don't understand why calling findHead here:

```
single x = length (snd(x)) == 1

toList board
    | board == [] = []
    | otherwise = filter single board

findHead board = head (toList board)
```

is not equivalent to calling toList here:

```
single x = length (snd(x)) == 1

toList board
    | board == [] = []
    | otherwise =  head (filter single board)
```

It seems to me that the two should be the same, but only the first one runs. Why aren't they interpreted to be the same? Could you explain this to me? In the code above, 'board' is meant to be a list of tuples which are each the form (x, [a,b,...]).

I've used 'head' in a few simpler things like:

```
union xs ys 
  | xs == [] = ys
  | ys == [] = xs
  | otherwise = union (tail xs)  (add (head xs) ys)
```

which seems to work as I would expect it would.

Comment: "but only the first one runs" - Does this mean that the second one hangs, or that it produces a different output, or that one results in an error?

Comment: You would need to call `head` in both cases, i.e. by changing `| board == [] = head []`. And then I hope you can see why `head` is a bad idea here.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, prefer (exhaustive!) pattern matching to partial projections such as `head` or `tail`.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `==[]` to check for the empty list. That imposes an `Eq` constraint for no reason and just looks odd. You should usually use pattern matching in this sort of context, instead of guards.  `union [] ys = ys` and `union (x:xs) ys = union xs (x:ys)`, for instance. If you really want an "is it empty", you should use `null`. Also, asking if the length of a list is 1 is potentially much less efficient than pattern matching it against the `[x]` or `[_]` pattern.

Comment: Also, in the future, it is very helpful if you tell us in English what the code is supposed to do and what it actually does, and to give an actual test case. Otherwise, figuring out how to fix it is like reading tea leaves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`head` is *partial*. In particular, `head []` doesn't return normally (throws an exception). This can be difficult to handle in Haskell which is why people often suggest that you avoid partial functions.

So how do we do that? We have to reflect failure *in the type*.

```
safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeHead []     = Nothing
safeHead (a:as) = Just a
```

A similar function can be made for `tail`

```
safeTail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
safeTail []     = Nothing
safeTail (a:as) = Just as
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take a step back and understand how pattern matching, recursion and single-linked lists work.  As various people have mentioned, the code you're writing is not going to work very well.

As an illustration here's how I would write the various functions in your question:

```
single :: (a, [b]) -> Bool    
single (_, [_]) = True
single _ = False

toList :: [(a, [b])] -> [(a, [b])]
toList board = filter single board

findHead :: [(a, [b])] -> Maybe (a, [b])
findHead [] = Nothing
findHead board = head (toList board)

-- This one actually does the same thing as the built-in `++` operator,
-- but for the sake of illustration, I'll implement it.
union :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union [] ys = ys
union (x:xs) ys = x : union xs ys
```